# Secured authentification for users Laravel 4

Tags: ssl, laravel, laravel-4, wamp, laravel-routing

I'm working on a new Laravel 4 project and i would like to secure the authentication route over the SSL protocol and honestly i searched for 2 days with no luck and i have no idea how to do that.

That's my routes.php file:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'guest'), function(){

/*==========================
| csrf PROTECTION
*///========================
Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf'), function(){

    /*==========================
    | Post Sign-in
    *///========================
    Route::post('/account/sign-in', array(
    'as'    => 'account-sign-in-post',
    'uses'  => 'AccountController@postSignIn'
    ));
});

/*==========================
| Get Sign-in
*///========================
Route::get('/account/sign-in', array(
'as'    => 'account-sign-in',
'uses'  => 'AccountController@getSignIn'
));

});
```

i would like to know if is that even possible using wamp, or it can be only done using a real host server, any help would be appreciated, and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Lots of Google hits... Looks like you need an HTTPS index. [Advanced Routing](http://daylerees.com/codebright/advanced-routing).

Answer (score 0):

You can force routes to serve using https. For example:

```
Route::get('account/sign-in', array('https', function()
{
    return 'Must be over HTTPS';
}));
```

ref: http://laravel.com/docs/routing